Azure DevOps Concurrency Lock To Prevent Concurrent Runs Multi-Stage Issue
I'm trying to prevent an Azure DevOps pipeline from allowing concurrent runs by two different agents to occur at the same time. I've followed the suggestions on this post to add a lock onto a variable group, and then reference said variable group in the pipeline yaml. This seems to work for singular staged pipelines, but when running on a pipeline with 4 stages where at least one pipeline stage is dependent on another one of the pipeline stages, and then queueing up two runs of the pipeline at roughly the same time, I found that this doesn't seem to function as expected.
Run 1 will start its first stage(s), and run 2 will state that it's waiting on the lock before it begins. This is what is expected. However, when run 1's first stage(s) finish, run 2's first stages will begin, and now run 1's second stage(s) are waiting for run 2 to be done with the lock.
This is resulting in the same broken behavior as before that I'm trying to prevent, and was hoping someone could point out my mistake so that the entirety of run 1 is completed before run 2 starts?
Here's the yaml. Build_Concurrency_Lock is the variable group with a lock, and Web-Stage.yml, TestKit-Stage.yml, and ClientInstaller-Stage.yml all have a dependsOn for Client-Stage.yml.
# CI Build Pipeline

name: 1.$(date:yy).$(date:MM).$(date:dd)$(rev:rr)

lockBehavior: sequential
variables:
  - group: Code-Sign
  - group: Build_Concurrency_Lock
  - name: PCode
    value: '-'



parameters:
  - name: Configuration
    displayName: 'Configuration'
    type: string
    default: Release
    values:
      - Release
      - Debug
  - name: ContinueOnTestError
    displayName: 'Continue On Test Error?'
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: IsDevTestBuild
    displayName: 'Is Developer Test Build?'
    type: boolean
    default: false

pool:
  name: TwoAgentPool

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - Root
  paths:
    include:
      - '*'
    exclude:
      - Builds/*
      - CommonAssemblyInfo.proj 

stages:
  - template: Templates/Stages/Client-Stage.yml
    parameters:
      ProductCode: ${{ variables.ProductCode }}
      Configuration: ${{ parameters.Configuration }}
      ContinueOnTestError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnTestError }}
      IsDevTestBuild: ${{ parameters.IsDevTestBuild }}

  - template: Templates/Stages/Web-Stage.yml
    parameters:
      ProductCode: ${{ variables.ProductCode }}
      Configuration: ${{ parameters.Configuration }}
      ContinueOnTestError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnTestError }}
      IsDevTestBuild: ${{ parameters.IsDevTestBuild }}

  - template: Templates/Stages/TestKit-Stage.yml
    parameters:
      ProductCode: ${{ variables.ProductCode }}
      ContinueOnTestError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnTestError }}
      IsDevTestBuild: ${{ parameters.IsDevTestBuild }}
      ${{ if eq(parameters.Configuration, 'Release') }}:
        Configuration: 'Release'
      ${{ else }}:
        Configuration: 'Debug'

  - template: Templates/Stages/ClientInstaller-Stage.yml
    parameters:
      ProductCode: ${{ variables.ProductCode }}
      Configuration: ${{ parameters.Configuration }}
      ContinueOnTestError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnTestError }}
      IsDevTestBuild: ${{ parameters.IsDevTestBuild }}


In theory, setting lockBehavior: sequential at the pipeline level should do what you need. But the problem is that there was a bug which prevents the correct behaviour. According to the link, the issue status is "Fixed - Pending Release" but there is no information at the moment about when the fix will be released.


However, when run 1's first stage finishes, run 2's first stages will begin, and now run 1's second stage(s) are waiting for run 2 to be done with the lock.

It seemed that the defining lockBehavior property on pipeline root level will cause this lock for every stage even some stages don’t consume the resource which configured with the Exclusive Lock. Then only one stage of all pipeline runs could access this specific resource only once at any given time. When the stage using the lock completed, then another stage could proceed to use the resource. Also, only one stage was allowed to continue.
The issue was still pending fix. If possible, please try and use exclusive locks of the stage levels until the resolution is released.
